# jquery ajax - how to use response in success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```html
page.php

$sqlQuery = "";
$result = $mysqli->query($sqlQuery);
if (mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli) > 0) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

I want to use response text in success but with if condition is not working.
How can i use with if.

Thanks for your help.

```
$.ajax({
    metod: "POST",
    url: "page.php",
    data: {data},
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response); // It is working
        notification("success"); // It is working

        // response text is succes or error

        if (response == 'success') {
            btnLabel.html("DONE"); // It is not working
        } else if (response == 'error') {
            btnLabel.html("ERROR"); // It is not working
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        notification("error"); // It is working
    }
});
```

Comment: show source code of page.php

Comment: can you use trim maybe there is unwanted space in there making the `==` wrong all the time

Comment: What is expected in `response` variable?

Comment: As an aside, you have a typo: `metod`.

Comment: Is your If condition is not working or btnLabel.html...?

Comment: Please show us `console.log(response);` gives result in console.

Comment: it might be possible that 'response' is not returning a string something like 'success' or 'error'. so can you show us that what is going to return from that page.php ?

Comment: add `dataType: "text",` also fix `method`

Comment: Thank you everyone I found my mistake :-)